# Finding the rank or index of some name in an array returned by query

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking

I am firing a query which returns minimum 1000 rows containing name, amount in order amount desc. I want the index of some name from that array, I don't know how to do it?

As I am using Ruby, I use arr.index(name)+1 method which returns the index properly.
But I want some MySQL query which gives me only numbers for that particular name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ranking functionality in MySQL.  The closest you can get is to use a variable:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM TABLE t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

That will add a column called rank to your output, that will be unique, incrementing, and starts at 1.

Comment: Thanks it works when i changed the above query with following one.

Th eonly change i made is @rownum = @rownum + 1 to @rownum := @rownum + 1 


SELECT  t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM tracks t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r